# How to add a new node at the end of an existing xml php

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schedule xmlns="schedule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schedule.xsd">
  <Event>
    <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
    <Lecture Classroom="A14">
      <Day>Wednesday</Day>
      <Time>09:00-11:00</Time>
    </Lecture>
    <Professor>Peter Parker</Professor>
    </Event>
  <Event>
    <Title>Constraint Satisfaction Problems</Title>
    <Lecture Classroom="E7">
      <Day>Monday</Day>
      <Time>19:00-21:00</Time>
    </Lecture>
    <Professor>David Peterson</Professor>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Title>Knowledge Representation in Web</Title>
    <Lecture Classroom="A3">
      <Day>Friday</Day>
      <Time>15:00-17:00</Time>
    </Lecture>
    <Professor>Dave Norton</Professor>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
    <Lecture Classroom="A2">
      <Day>Monday</Day>
      <Time>19:00-21:00</Time>
    </Lecture>
    <Professor>Michael Bay</Professor>
  </Event>
 </Schedule>
```

and i want to add **a new "Event"** in the **end of the above xml** like this

```
<Event>
  <Title>Maths</Title>
    <Lecture Classroom="B1">
      <Day>Monday</Day>
      <Time>19:00-20:00</Time>
    </Lecture>
    <Professor>Will Robes</Professor>
  </Event>
```

**The code** i tried so far creates the elements succesfull but writes them to wrong position in the file.**Here is the code** https://pastebin.com/qUqaab3SB

Comment: You XML contains an invalid namespace definition. `<Schedule xmlns="schedule"/>` The value of the xmlns attribute needs to be a valid URI. Or you remove it (if you do not use a namespace)

Comment: Yeah you have right i removed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are just finding the first `<Event>` tag and adding the information to that...

```
// find the Event tag
$root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('Event')->item(0);
```

What you need to do is create a new `<Event>` tag, add all the information to this tag and then add this new event to the end of the current document.  So replace the above line with...

```
// Create the Event tag
$root = $xmldoc->createElement("Event");
// Add it into the existing document
$xmldoc->documentElement->appendChild($root);
```